# React JS Invariant Violation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am fairly new to ReactJS so I am still learning the rope, but I am getting an error when trying to incorporate react-router into my application.  The lovely error that I am getting is:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `App`.

I have searched around for this error and saw a couple of fixes that I don't believe apply to my situation.  The most common error is missing a 'return' method, but I am pretty sure I am not missing one.

Here is the code in my index.js:

```
import './styles/main.css'

import Contact from './components/Contact.jsx';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

And my App.jsx looks like:

```
import React from 'react';

import Link from 'react-router'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
          <div className="wrapper">
            <header>
              <h1>Rest Test Contact List</h1>
              <nav>
                <ul className="navigation">
                  <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
                  <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </header>
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
      )
    }
}
```

And help on this error would be much appreciated.  I have been scratching my head on this for a few days.

Thanks!

Comment: One thing I noticed is in App.jsx you're not destructuring your import of `Link` correctly. It should be `import { Link } from 'react-router'`. That could be the cause of why the use of `Link` as a component (in your App's render method) is undefined. I say 'could be' because I'm not able to go through all the setup just to test it.

Comment: You are awesome!  That did fix it.  Can you explain to me why I needed the braces for importing just that one thing from react-router, whereas you don't need to do that for others like React or ReactDOM?

Comment: Sure! I'll write up an answer with a more thorough explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `App.jsx` you're not destructuring your import of `Link` correctly. It should be

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
```

That would cause the use of `Link` as a component (in your App's render method) to be undefined.

The [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) syntax makes it possible to extract data from objects and save them as such at the same time. ES6 introduced this shorthand for ease of use. In ES5 this would look like:

```
var Link = require('react-router').Link
```

But remember, this only works for when you're accessing children of an object (the submodule in the case of the imported modules you're using). That is why you do not need it when importing React or ReactDOM; you're importing the entire thing. But that doesn't mean likewise can't be done for those other libraries. For React, you could import `Component` directly, and reference it by name

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

And then you'd use it like:

```
export default class App extends Component { ... }
                                 ^
```

Notice that you're not using `React.Component`? Its because we've already imported it using the same destructuring syntax as with `Link` from `react-router`.

Comment: You could do the same with `render` from ReactDOM, since its the most common use of ReactDOM. Just `import { render } from 'react-dom';` (mind the lower-case *r* in render!) and then just `render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));`. Save yourself a few bytes.